# Lambda-API gateway : "message": "Internal server error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, sam

I am using AWS CodeStar (Lambda + API Gateway) to build my serverless API. My lambda function works well in the Lambda console but strangely throws this error when I run the code on AWS CodeStar:

> "message": "Internal server error"

Kindly help me with this issue.

```
import json
import os
import bz2
import pprint
import hashlib
import sqlite3
import re
from collections import namedtuple
from gzip import GzipFile
from io import BytesIO
from botocore.vendored import requests
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def handler(event, context):

    logger.info('## ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES')
    logger.info(os.environ)
    logger.info('## EVENT')
    logger.info(event)



    n = get_package_list()
    n1 = str(n)

    dat = {"total_pack":n1}
    return {'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            'body': json.dumps(dat)
    }


def get_package_list():

    url = "http://amazonlinux.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2/core/2.0/x86_64/c60ceaf6dfa3bc10e730c9e803b51543250c8a12bb009af00e527a598394cd5e/repodata/primary.sqlite.gz"

    db_filename = "dbfile"


    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    remote_data = resp.raw.read()

    cached_fh = BytesIO(remote_data)
    compressed_fh = GzipFile(fileobj=cached_fh)

    with open(os.path.join('/tmp',db_filename), "wb") as local_fh:
        local_fh.write(compressed_fh.read())

    package_obj_list = []

    db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join('/tmp',db_filename))

    c = db.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT name FROM packages')
    for package in c.fetchall():
        package_obj_list.append(package)


    no_of_packages = len(package_obj_list)

    return no_of_packages
```

**Expected Result:** should return an Integer (`no_of_packages`).

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: You  can check the cloudwatch logs generated by lambda and API Gateway to figure out what went wrong.